# conditional probability chest of draws

Tags: probability

You have a chest of $8$ drawers. With probability $1/2$, you   put a letter in one of the drawers. With probability $1/2$, you don't put a letter in any drawer. I open the first $7$ drawers, all are empty. What is the probability there is a letter in the $8th$ drawer? I thought the answer was $1/16$ but apparently its $1/9$ can any one explain why?

Comment: In order to have your question received positively, consider including your own attempt at the problem and indicating where you think the issue might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the event in which there is a letter in the $8$th drawer.

Let $B$ denote the event in which the first $7$ drawers are all empty.

Then $P(A|B)=\cfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\cfrac{\frac12\cdot\frac18}{\frac12\cdot(1-\frac78)+(1-\frac12)\cdot1}=\cfrac19$.

Comment: can you explain what the terms in the denominator are please.

Comment: @astrochris: In the denominator, we split the event $B$ into two **disjoint** events. In the first event - you put a letter in one of the drawers, and in the second event - you did not put a letter in one of the drawers.

Comment: @astrochris: Thus, $\color\red{\frac12}$ is the probability that you put a letter in one of the drawers and $\color\red{1-\frac78}$ is the probability that you did not put it in any of the first $7$ drawers, while $\color\red{1-\frac12}$ is the probability that you did not put a letter in one of the drawers and $\color\red{1}$ is the probability that you did not put it in any of the first $7$ drawers.

Comment: @astrochris If $C$ is the event that a letter was put into one of the drawers, then you can write $P(B) = P(B | C)P(C) + P(B | \overline{C})P(\overline{C})$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way:

Think of it as a chest of $2\times8=16$ drawers and put a letter in one of the drawers.

After opening $7$ empty drawers there are $9$ drawers left and in exactly one of them there is a letter.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the first seven drawers were empty either $A\cup B$ where:

- $A$: The letter is in the eighth drawer: $\mathsf P(A)=\tfrac 12 \tfrac 18$
- $B$: The letter is in no drawer: $\mathsf P(B)=\tfrac 12$

  - $A,B$ are disjoint

So by the definition of conditional probability

$$\mathsf P(A\mid A\cup B) ~=~ \dfrac{\color{grey}{\tfrac 12 \tfrac {\color{black}{1}}8}}{\color{grey}{\tfrac 12 \tfrac {\color{black}{1}}8+\tfrac 12 \tfrac {\color{black}{8}}8}}~=~\dfrac 19$$

$\blacksquare$