# 8 Drawer Desk Conditional Probability Problem: Use Bayes' Theorem using the given statement

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem

> A desk has eight drawers. There is a probability of 1/2 that someone placed a letter in one of the desk's eight drawers and a probability of 1/2 that this person didn't place a letter in any of the desk's eight drawers. You open the first 7 drawers and find that they are all empty. What is the probability that the 8th drawer has a letter in it?

This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4690507/1230700) makes use of a slightly different Event A while this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1895879) takes advantage of $P(A \cap B)$. I want to use the alternative form $P(A) * P(B|A)$ instead. This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4683078/determining-event-b-in-a-conditional-probability-word-problem) touches on the other part of the disjoint equation in the denominator that I am trying to figure out. Here is what I have so far:

Let $A$ denote the event in which there is a letter in the 8th drawer.

Let $B$ denote the event in which the first 7 drawers are all empty.

Then $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A) * P(B|A)}{P(B)}$

$P(A) = \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{8}$ since there's a 1/2 chance that there's a letter in the drawers and only 1 of the 8 possible scenarios is there a letter in the 8th drawer.

$P(B) = P(B|A)*P(A) + P(B|A')*P(A')$ - This means the probability of having the first seven drawers empty is equal to:

- The probability that the first seven drawers are empty given that the
  letter is in the 8th drawer $P(B|A)$ times the probability that the
  letter is in the 8th drawer $P(A)$ PLUS
- The probability that the first seven drawers are empty given that the letter is NOT in the 8th drawer $P(B|A')$ times the probability that the letter is NOT in the 8th drawer $P(A')$

$P(B|A)$ = 1 since if it's in the 8th drawer, the other seven have to be empty since there's only one letter.

$P(A)$ was already calculated as $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{8}$

$P(B|A')$ = unsure

$P(A')$ = $(\frac{1}{2} * \frac{7}{8}) + \frac{1}{2} * 1$ (I think this is true - 1/2 of the time we will be in the letter state and there will be 7 out of 8 states in which the letter is not in the 8th spot). The other 1/2 of the time when there is no letter, it will be 8/8 times that the letter is not in the 8th spot.

I am focused on filling in the gaps on this specific method. There are other elegant solutions that I understand, but this is how I've been solving other Baye's Theorem problems, so I want to solidify my understanding by pointing out where I went wrong or how I can count $P(B|A')$

Judging by the correct answers, if everything I wrote is correct, then $P(B|A')$ has to be 8/15, but what does 8/15 represent? Also, I wouldn't know what this is beforehand, so I'd like to know how to calculate this.

Comment: These problems get simpler if you imagine that there is a $9^{th}$ drawer...representing the "not the other $8$" option.  Thus, at the start there is a $\frac 12$ chance we are dealing with drawer $9$ and a $\frac {1}{16}$ chance for each of the others.  Try it that way.

Comment: Pro Tip: You have event $A$ indicating "it *is* here", and event $B$ indicating "it *is not* there".  It would be less confusing if you were more consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letter is exclusively either:

- $A$: In the eighth drawer with probability $1/16$.
- $B'$: In one among the other drawers with probability $7/16$.
- $A'\cap B$: Not in any drawer with probability $1/2$ .

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A~\cap B~)&= 1/16 &\text{because }&A~\cap B~ = A\\\mathsf P(A'\cap B') &= 7/16 &&A'\cap B' = B'\\\mathsf P(A'\cap B~) &=1/2\\\mathsf P(A~\cap B')&=0\end{align}$$

Use this to calculate your probabilities.  Such as: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\mid B) &=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)}{\mathsf P(B)}\\&=\dfrac{1/16}{9/16}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. I imagined that there were two desks, one with letters in each of them and one without (8 "full" *& 8 "empty"). From there, if you draw this out, you can calculate all the probabilities that you just described.

Answer (score 3):

You don't explicitly say so, but I'm assuming that if there is a letter in one of the drawers, it's *a priori* equally likely to be in any of them.

Assume we perform $16$ trials.  In $8$ of those trials, there's no letter.  In the other $8$ trials, there's a letter in a different one of the $8$ drawers.

Given the information we now have, there are $9$ remaining cases and each of them is equally likely.  So the probability that there's a letter in the remaining drawer is $\frac 19$.

Comment: Hi Robert. Are you ***the*** famous ***LAWYER*** Robert Shore? Or are you just using his name and picture? Nice bumping into you here. Have you considered answering questions at https://law.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Scexit Both the picture and name are mine, and I am a lawyer.  I've never thought of myself as famous, though, and I have enough namesakes that it's very likely one or more of them is a lawyer as well.  However, I doubt any of them would have my picture.

Comment: I recognized you from one of your cases. Have you considered answering questions at https://law.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Scexit Which case?  For reasons I trust are obvious, I’d be more than a little reluctant at writing anything on a legal Web site that could be construed as legal advice.